# Occurrence count on text file not working when trying to make a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
'Bill','Bill','Bill','Jake','Jake','Mike','Mike','Mike','Mike'
```

I am trying to count the number occurrences for each name. These names can always change so I can't hard code them. I've seen other examples that were formatted differently and I tried to replicate my code as close as possible, but it still doesn't work.

My code:

```
text = open("test.txt", "r") 

d = dict() 

for line in text: 

    line = line.strip()
    line = line.lower()
    line = line.replace('"', '').replace("'", "")
    words = line.split(" ") 

    for word in words:

        if word in d: 
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else: 
            d[word] = 1

for key in list(d.keys()): 
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

My output:

```
'Bill','Bill','Bill','Jake','Jake','Mike','Mike','Mike','Mike',: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting by space which is absent in the lines (but comma is there).

Try changing:

```
words = line.split(" ")
```

to:

```
words = line.split(",")
```

Comment: sorry about that i wasn't really understanding if that just split them automatically or not. thank you for the reply as now i understand that whatever is present in the file is what you put there to split.

Comment: i will i just need to wait 5 more minutes to accept the answer